# I want to rewrite Url with URI Routing of my CodeIgniter App

Tags: codeigniter, url-routing

I am using codeigniter, I have URL like this (http://localhost/en/home/submit). My App has the same url with multi languages. like

- http://localhost/fr/home/submit
- http://localhost/es/home/submit
- http://localhost/de/home/submit

I want to rewrite this url with URI Routing like this

- http://localhost/en/submit
- http://localhost/fr/submit
- http://localhost/de/submit
- http://localhost/es/submit

How should I set up URI Routing?

Comment: You have asked 10 questions which have received an average of 3 answers, many in-depth solutions to the problems you stated. Maybe now is a good time to go back and accept some of the answers you found helpful :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need the opposite of what ulvund posted:

```
$route['(en|fr|es|de)/submit'] = "home/submit/$1";
```

... where Home is the controller and submit is the method.

Answer (score 1):

Use Apache's mod_rewrite:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

put this in a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(en|fr|es|de)/home/(.*)$ $1/$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

In routes.php

```
$route['^(en|fr|es|de)/home/(.*)$'] = "$1/$2";
```

if that doesn't work try:

```
$route['(en|fr|es|de)/home/(.*)'] = "$1/$2";
```